# XSLT 3.0 Dynamic select with variable in apply-templates?

Tags: xslt

I want to apply templates to a set of nodes where part of the `select` path is a variable. I'm using Saxon-HE 9.8 (awesome lib!)

I'm trying to achieve the following

```
<variable name="x" select="string('baz')"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="foo/bar/$x"/>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there a syntax that will allow me to dynamically construct the select XPath for this `apply-templates` instruction? Or, is there another technique for dynamically achieving this effect? I even tried pushing this down to my `<xsl:template match=foo/bar/$x>` but no luck.

My motivation here is in my application the variable value is coming from *a separate configuration file*. Based on the configuration I need to run templates matching specific path segments driven by config strings...

Comment: Mads Hansen has told you how to do it, but hasn't explained why your code doesn't work. A variable in XSLT/XPath represents a value; it doesn't represent a fragment of an XPath expression. If the value of `$foo` is the string `"baz"`, then `a/b/c/$foo` means `a/b/c/"baz"`, not `a/b/c/baz`. To evaluate arbitrary XPath expressions that are supplied dynamically (at run-time) as strings, you need the xsl:evaluate instruction.

Comment: I'm rather surprised that such a seemingly common use case (dynamically constructed XPath) isn't addressed by XSLT except through the broad `xsl:evaluate` instruction? Would an alternative would be to use XSLT to generate other XSLTs using the variable values from my config file?

Comment: Yes, generating XSLT and then executing it is another way of doing it.

Comment: Many thanks Michael, appreciate your XSLT wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables are always going to be a simple string value expressing the name of an element, then one option would be to match a little more generically on an element and then use the string variable in a predicate to filter for a match of the element name:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="foo/bar/*[local-name() = $x]"/>
```

With Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE, you could leverage [`xsl:evaluate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate) and do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" as="node()*">
  <xsl:evaluate xpath="concat('foo/bar/',$x)" context-item="."/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$var"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mads, but the select above doesn't seem to match anything, even if I substitute the `$x` for the string value directly.

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code it to `select="foo/bar/baz"`? There is a `baz` element that is a child of `foo/bar`, and your context is the parent of the `foo` element? It is difficult to diagnose why it won't. You haven't provided an example of the XML or the context in which this XSLT snippet is being evaluated.

Comment: My XPath tester must be old (Webstorm), as your solution works in online testers. For additional info, my use case required me to check the text value of the matched node: `[*[local-name() = "bodysale"]/text() = "T"]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a [static parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-params) `<xsl:param name="x" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'baz'"/>` for the value and then use a [shadow attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes) in the form of `_select="foo/bar/{$x}"` you can even construct the path dynamically, but only when compiling the XSLT.

In a static parameter you can of course pull in a configuration file and use values from it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="config-uri" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2018/config-example1.xml'"/>
  <xsl:param name="config-doc" static="yes" as="document-node()" select="doc($config-uri)"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="item[@type = 'foo']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of _select="{$config-doc/map/from[@key = 'foo']}"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item[@type = 'bar']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of _select="{$config-doc/map/from[@key = 'bar']}"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvX/1

Another option I didn't mention in my first answer but that is also a viable way with Saxon 9.8 or any other XSLT 3 processor is the use of XSLT to create XSLT and then to use the `transform` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-transform) to run that generated XSLT. That approach has the advantage that it works with Saxon 9.8 HE where `xsl:evaluate` is not supported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
    exclude-result-prefixes="axsl"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="config-uri" as="xs:string" select="'https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2018/config-example1.xml'"/>
  <xsl:param name="config-doc" as="document-node()" select="doc($config-uri)"/>

  <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

  <xsl:variable name="generated-xslt">
      <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
          <axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="$config-doc/map/from">
              <axsl:template match="item[@type = '{@key}']">
                  <axsl:copy>
                      <axsl:value-of select="{.}"/>
                  </axsl:copy>
              </axsl:template>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </axsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence 
        select="transform(map {
            'source-node' : .,
            'stylesheet-node' : $generated-xslt
          })?output"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvX/2

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I can use a _static_ parameter in my case as it's not global and the values are pulled from a separate file?

Comment: It is true that a static parameter needs to be global, your snippet does not show any need to have a local parameter or variable. As for using a configuration file, you can do that in a static parameter preceding the one setting up `x`. I will edit the answer to show an example.