# creating xpath dynamically in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to fetch part of xml from a look-up-xml using some dynamic xpath located in my input xml.
when I have tried to add the path hard-coded it is working perfect and getting the desired result for me.
But when I am trying the same with a variable it is not working.

**input**

```
<root>
    <path
        location="/legitem/front[1]/title[1]">
        <msg>TITLE</msg>
    </path>
    <path
        location="/legitem/front[1]/longtitle[1]">
        <msg>LONGTITLE</msg>
    </path>
</root>
```

**XSLT2.0**

```
<xsl:variable name="fetch_content" select="document('source.xml')/legitem/front[1]/title[1]" as="node()"/>

<!-- working for above fixed xpath -->
<xsl:copy-of select="$fetch_content"/>

<!-- O\P : correct -->
--copies the content of <title>
```

But not fetching the content when trying to use variable to make dynamic

```
<xsl:variable name="LookUpXml" select="document('source.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="loc" select="substring-after(@location, '/legitem/')"/>

<xsl:copy-of select="$main_file//$loc"/>

<!-- O\P : wrong -->
front[1]/title[1]
front[1]/longtitle[1]
```

If anyone has any idea on how I could achieve this that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks...

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible with XSLT 2.0... See this for example if you could switch to XSLT 3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224145/xslt-3-0-dynamic-select-with-variable-in-apply-templates

Comment: XSLT 3 (not 2) has an `xsl:evaluate` element that can do that but it is only supported in the commercial editions of Saxon 9 or recently in all editions of Saxon 10. So which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: using saxon9 HE. and already tried `<xsl:value-of select="$LookUpXml/saxon:evaluate(@location)" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>` before posting the problem here. unfortunately getting _Saxon extension functions are not available under Saxon-HE_

Comment: Well, in XSLT 3 there is an `xsl:evaluate` element but for HE you will only have support for that with the Saxon 10 release of this year. The extension function is only available in the commercial editions. But see the link potame mentioned in his comment where you also have an answer to construct XSLT on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly do it by matching to the name() of the node, but it depends how much of the path is dynamic

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$main_file//front[1]/*[name()=$loc][1]" />
```